# list index out of range....?

Tags: python

When I run this code it says list index out of range, even if I have 6 idle on my folder. I've been stuck on this for so long. I keep rewatching the tutorial to fix this, if you need more code: https://pastebin.com/Pby3gBmG

```
import pygame
from support import import_folder

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.import_character_assets()
        self.frame_index = 0
        self.animation_speed = 0.15
        self.image = self.animations['idle'][self.frame_index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos) 
        
        
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0,0)
        self.speed = 8
        self.gravity = 0.8
        self.jump_speed = -16
        
    def import_character_assets(self):
        character_path = '../graphics/character/'
        self.animations = {'idle':[],  'run':[], 'jump':[], 'fall':[]}
        
        for animation in self.animations.keys():
            full_path = character_path + animation
            self.animations[animation] = import_folder(full_path)
        
    def get_input(self):        
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a]: # left
            self.direction.x = -1
        elif keys[pygame.K_d]: # right
            self.direction.x = 1
            
        else:
            self.direction.x = 0
            
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.jump()
            
    def apply_gravity(self):
        self.direction.y += self.gravity
        self.rect.y += self.direction.y
        
    def jump(self):
        self.direction.y = self.jump_speed
        
                        
    def update(self):
        self.get_input()
        self.rect.x += self.direction.x * self.speed
```

Comment: You forgot to post the stack trace.

Comment: Please, add the stack trace so we can find the issue.

I see you are initializing the animations with empty array         
`self.animations = {'idle':[],  'run':[], 'jump':[], 'fall':[]}`


In python if you try to access an index in an empty array you will get the `IndexError: list index out of range`


If for some reason `self.import_character_assets()` is failing to populate the idle animation array you will get the error on the line where you call
`self.image = self.animations['idle'][self.frame_index]`

Comment: sorry for not adding the stack trace, this is the stack trace:

https://pastebin.com/MXtTY3p6

Comment: Please edit that into your question.

Answer (score 0):

From my assumption, please check this `import_folder` function's input path, as when you call this `import_character_assets`, its still updating `self.animations[animation]` with empty list

```
def import_character_assets(self):
    character_path = '../graphics/character/'
    self.animations = {'idle':[],  'run':[], 'jump':[], 'fall':[]}
    
    for animation in self.animations.keys():
        full_path = character_path + animation
        self.animations[animation] = import_folder(full_path) #resulting empty list
```